# How do you integrate $z^2 = y^2 +x^2$ using cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

I'm trying to use:
$$\int_{0}^{h} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}r\:dr\:d\theta\:dz$$
but I'm not totally sure if I should replace the x and y with the $r\:cos(\theta)$ and $r\:sin(\theta)$ respectively that are used for cyllindrical coordinates. It has to be integrated from the $xy$ plane to a height $h$

What should I do?

Comment: What is the region over which you are integrating?

Comment: This looks like something halfway done when converting from cartesian to cylindrical. Please show the original question and what you did working on it.

Comment: @zipirovich I have to integrate it from the $xy$ plane to a height $h$

Comment: Integrate **what**? The limits of integration are given in cartesian coordinates, since there are $x$ and $y$ in them -- so they are still written as in an integral **before** switching to cylindrical coordinates. But the integrand and the differential are given **after** switching to cylindrical coordinated, judging by $r$ and $\theta$ in them. The whole hybrid doesn't make much sense. That's why I asked to see the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but be careful with notation. In your integral, $r$ is a variable, but you will integrate from $0$ to $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: That is blatantly false since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  How can the integration limit on $r$ contain $r$, which is a "dummy" parameter?

Comment: That's why I assumed $r$ was simply a dummy variable and used $\rho$ as limit of integration.

Comment: But then $\rho\ne \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, as you asserted incorrectly.

Comment: I assumed that he copied the transformation to cylindrical coordinates from the textbook as it is, and didn't pay attention that the same $r$ was used as variable and limit of integration. In this case, I changed the transformation to $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$. God knows how many times I accidentally forgot it when learning Calculus...